# Resource layout gaps between

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I made this layout on Android, but as you see when I insert the photo it makes a gap between the line above and below it, what could be the problem? I tried redoing it but when I try to add all four of them it suddenly makes that [image of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gflbB.png)

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/top"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="VTMC - Android kursai"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:background="#8f4426"
        android:gravity="center"        />
        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mountains"
             android:layout_below="@id/top"/>





    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Aprašymas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"

        android:textColor="#696969"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:background="#f9b282"
        android:gravity="center"



        />

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:text="VTMC - Android kursai"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="#C0C0C0"
         android:paddingTop="20dp"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you sure it isn't the image that looks like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use **android:scaleType** to **centerCrop**

```
 <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/mountains"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:layout_below="@id/top"/>
```

centerCrop supports by udacity

Comment: Thank you, this helped   android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/mountains"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_below="@id/top"/>
```

Comment: Im doing it on the https://labs.udacity.com/android-visualizer/ and sadly it doesn't support the "fitXY" command, Thanks for the reply

Comment: You can use constraint layout instead of linear layout. @KarolisGumbis